# Why can't I execute an anonymous block in PL / SQL?

Tags: oracle

I want to make a procedure in an anonymous block, which will display information about all database sessions that have unclosed transactions from the data dictionary views

```
BEGIN 
    select s.sid, s.serial#, s.username from v$transaction t inner join 
    v$session s on t.addr = s.taddr; 
END;
```

But when I try to call it, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use anonymous block? Without begin and end you can see the result set. If you want to use this block then you should use an into part with variables or a cursor loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to follow your anonymous block with a '/', to tell oracle to stop parsing and start executing.

That said, your code still will just throw an error because you need to SELECT .... INTO some variable to hold the results of your SELECT.

And that said, even if you provide the correct variables and INTO syntax, your code still will not do what you expect, because PL/SQL is a server-side process that has no ability to display output.  The closest it can come is to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE, but that just writes to a buffer that is returned, upon completion of the entire procedure, to the client.  It is then up to the client to decide what do do with it.

And all that said, why do you think you need an anonymous PL/SQL block just to execute a simple query?

*And all that said*, screen shots of terminal sessions are very hard to read. It's actually very easy to simply  copy the text from the terminal, and paste that into your postings. Then select the pasted text and click the 'code sample' icon of the edit window menu to set it off as formatted code.

Comment: According to university homework, an anonymous block should be used for this task

Comment: Fine. Then address the other points I made.

Comment: I read it, now I will try to remake my code

Answer (score 2):

If you really need an anonymous block, you can use the following code:

```
begin
  for r_rows in (
    select s.sid, s.serial#, s.username
      from v$transaction t
      inner join v$session s on t.addr = s.taddr) loop
      
    dbms_output.put_line(r_rows.sid);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

You must write the other columns in the dbms_output.put_line statement.

Comment: When you do someone's homework for them, they learn nothing.